# Conflicto 2 proyectos con rutas locales php

Tags: php, rutas, localhost, requests

Tengo 2 proyectos en php:

*Proyecto **a**, corriendo en servidor integrado de php en puerto localhost:9000

*Proyecto **b**, corriendo en wamp con puerto localhost

Proyecto **a** tiene un ajax que va a la dirección del segundo para consultar un método, entonces en la url de la petición pongo:

```
var url = 'http://localhost/portal/datos';
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("POST", url, true);


http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
http.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Me da error 404 y si la cambio la ruta por:

```
var url = 'localhost/portal/datos';
```

me dirige a localhost:9000/localhost/portal/datos

Comment: Y la pregunta del millón es ... ¿ Seguro que hay algo en `http://localhost/portal/datos` ? Demuestra nos que si, que en esa URL hay algo.

Comment: por que no mejor le pones un alias a tus proyectos para poder diferenciarlos bien.

Comment: Gracias compañero, a la final lo resolví poniéndole alias a uno de ellos. Muchas gracias por sus respuestas.